# Argument 1 must be a data frame or a named atomic vector

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, r-markdown

I am trying to knit a codebook with R markdown and the package "codebook". 
But when I click "knit" the following error occurs:

```
[...]
Could not summarize item pfbp. Error: Argument one must be a data frame or a named atomic vector.
[...]
```

I don't want to copy the whole code in here, but that's the summary of item pfbp:

```
> codebook_data$pfbp
<Labelled integer>: personal financial benefits decrease in productivity
  [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [29] NA NA NA NA NA  4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  5
 [57] NA  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  5 NA NA NA  3  2  1 NA NA NA NA NA
 [85] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  5 NA NA NA NA NA  5 NA  4  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[113] NA NA NA NA NA NA  3  3 NA NA NA  5 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  5 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[141] NA NA NA NA NA  5 NA NA  3  4  4 NA NA NA  5  5 NA NA NA  4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[169] NA NA  4 NA NA NA NA NA NA  4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[197] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  5 NA  3 NA  5 NA NA NA NA  5  4
[225] NA NA  1 NA NA  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  5 NA NA NA NA  2  5 NA  5 NA NA NA NA
[253] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  4  5 NA  3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  5 NA NA NA
[281] NA NA NA NA  5 NA NA NA  4 NA NA  1  4 NA NA NA NA NA  5 NA NA  5 NA NA NA NA NA NA
[309] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  3 NA NA NA NA NA
[337] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[365] NA NA  2 NA NA NA NA NA  3 NA NA NA NA NA  5 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  2 NA NA NA  2
[393] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  4 NA  5 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[421] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  5 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[449] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  5  5 NA  4
[477] NA NA NA  4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  2  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[505] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[533] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  5 NA NA  4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  5
[561] NA  5  4  5
Labels:
 value                label
     1      Trifft nicht zu
     2 Trifft eher nicht zu
     3          teils-teils
     4       Trifft eher zu
     5            Trifft zu
     0           Weiß nicht
> summary(codebook_data$pfbp)
          [0] Weiß nicht      [1] Trifft nicht zu [2] Trifft eher nicht zu 
                       1                        5                        8 
         [3] teils-teils       [4] Trifft eher zu            [5] Trifft zu 
                       8                       17                       29 
                    NA's 
                     496 
> class(codebook_data$pfbp)
[1] "haven_labelled"
```

I don't understand this error message. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Try to convert it to a data frame using `df <- as.data.frame(your_data)`.

Comment: Your output shows that `pfbp` is a "Labelled integer" (whatever that happens to be, probably it's a data structure offered by some package), which doesn't appear to be a named vector (a base R data structure). Also, it is unclear what code resulted in the error.

Comment: it seems like OP is using the `labelled` package @Roland

Comment: @Anna I'm willing to help, if you can add the full code and data into your question (or alternatively, enough that I can reproduce the error)